# Calculating the time complexity of Bubble sort

Tags: summation, algorithms, asymptotics

### Question

I am interested in finding the time complexity of [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) by simplifying the summation.

### My Approach

$$\sum _{i=0}^{i=n-1}\,\,\sum _{j=0}^{j=n-i-1}1\text{(some constant)}=\sum _{i=0}^{i=n-1} n-i$$
$$\sum _{i=0}^{i=n-1} n-\sum _{i=0}^{i=n-1}i=n^{2}-\frac{n (n-1)}{2}$$

$$=\frac{n (n+1)}{2}$$ i.e $O(n^{2})$

Am i correct?
Can i say that #of comparison in bubble sort will be $$=\frac{n (n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel so # of comparsion in simple bubble sortwould be $\frac{n (n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: In the worst case, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct (and consequently, so are you), but you should be able to avoid the worst-case scenario.

For example, pre-compute the number of unrespected order in a first run and choose to go in the other direction if it's bigger than half the size of your list.
Intuitively, this would yield a $\frac{n^2}{4}$ complexity.