# What is the minimum number of times one must run this algorithm so the sequence ends up ordered?

Tags: algorithms

I am teaching programming for someone and in the course of the lecturing, I have devised an ordering algorithm. It works as follows:

> > - Given a sequence $k_0$ of $n$ diferent integers.
> > - Read position $1$ and $2$. If $p(1)>p(2)$, switch them. If not, do nothing.
> > - Read position $2$ and $3$. If $p(2) > p(3)$, switch them. If not, do nothing.
> > - $\dots$
> > - Repeat until $n-1$.
> > - Obtain the sequence $k_1$ which is the result of the previous algorithm.
>
> - Apply the algorithm to $k_1$, obtain $k_2$ and then apply the algorithm to $k_2$, etc until the sequence is ordered.

Now, I could end this algorithm by adding the following condition: If at each step in the ordering of $k', k'',\dots$, it didn't change anything then the algorithm ends. But I have noticed that if I let it running for a sequence of $n$ different integers, it will eventually end.

**My question:** What is the minimum number of times the algorithm must run to order all possible sequences of $n$ different integers?

**What I have tried:** I tried to think about defining the most unordered sequence (the sequence that will take a biggest number of steps to end) but I have failed to guess what it is. I've made some examples with $123,321,213, \dots , 1234,4231,1231, \dots$ but this didn't seem to give me a clue. Nevertheless, I think this approach is a good idea and would like to get a hint at how to end this following this approach.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848544/calculating-the-time-complexity-of-bubble-sort)

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Altough it answers my question (I have also found the answer in a book on algorithm analysis book), I'd like to be able to actually define the "most unordered sequence" and proceed from this.

Comment: I believe any sequence in which $\ p_1>p_2>\dots > p_n\ $ will be "most unordered", in the sense that it will require $\ n-1\ $ runs of the algorithm for it to be sorted, and no other sequence can require any more than that.

Comment: I believe the minimum is zero, attained when the sequence is ordered to start wsith. Are you sure you didn't mean **maximum**? (Minimum = smallest, maximum = biggest.)

Comment: @bof Minimum for all sequences as I have written.